# Does Islam make any distinction by caste when it comes to marriage?

Tags: nikah, caste

Does Islam make/suggest any distinction/restriction by caste when it comes to making alliances (finding a partner for marriage)? Additionally, does it allow or even mention about caste?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### *Does Islam make/suggest any distinction/restriction by caste when it comes to finding a partner for marriage?*

The Holy Prophet (pbuh) asks us to marry the most religious woman.

> **Narrated Abu Huraira:**
> The Prophet said, "A woman is married for four things, i.e., her wealth, her lineage (family status), her beauty and her religion. So you should marry the religious woman (otherwise) you will be a losers. ***Sahih Al-Bukhari Volume 7, Book 62, Hadith 27.***

As you see, in the above Hadith, It is the religion that matters, not family status (which, in modern times can be called caste), wealth or anything else. Even the people who are invited to the marriage should not be distincted.

> **Narrated Abu Huraira:**
> The worst food is that of a wedding banquet to which only the rich are invited while the poor are not invited. And he who refuses an invitation (to a banquet) disobeys Allah and His Apostle . ***Volume 7, Book 62, Hadith 106***

So, Islam doesn't condemn any inter-caste marriage. The only ground at which a marriage proposal can be rejected is the taqwa (religoiusness and righteousness).

### *Does Islam allow or even mention about caste?*

Allah has divided us into tribes so we may know each other, not to fight and discriminate. If a man is noble and superior to another, it is only through righteousness and taqwa.

> O mankind, indeed We have created you from male and female and made you peoples and tribes that you may know one another. Indeed, the most noble of you in the sight of Allah is the most righteous of you. Indeed, Allah is Knowing and Acquainted. [***Qur'an 49:13.***](http://quran.com/49/13)

#### ۚ  وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ (And Allah is the All-Knower, the Wise)

**Jazaakallah...**

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tabrez.
You second exactly what I thought, I believe no religion should discriminate.
I asked because one of my muslim friend was recently turned down for an alliance on the basis of caste. Undoubtedly they are in loss not my friend.

And sorry I cannot mark the answer as useful as I am pretty new to this portal and don't have enough points to do that.
Thanks for your reply again.

Comment: @RaviSanwal, hope the update helps

Comment: This answer doesn't address one of the four attributes mentioned in that same hadith -- a woman's lineage.

Comment: @ashes999, could you explain?

Comment: @ashes999 Can you please explain more. The basic question here is that whether or not it is allowed or mentioned in Islam to make a difference based on caste, specifically for seeking an alliance, and in general for anything else.

Comment: The hadith quoted says "a woman is married for four [...] her family lineage [...]" -- this is essentially an indicator of her status, or "caste". The answer does not address this.

Comment: @ashes999, the hadith says that  we shouldn't marry a person based on any of the 4 things in the hadith but the righteousness. This was the answer to question. The hadith rules out considering any family lineage or status itself and seldom needs explanation.

Comment: @TabrezAhmed actually, scholars say that you can choose any of the four; but rasulullah pointed out the best (deen). He said, as the hadith text says, **a woman is married** for four things"

Comment: @ashes999, But the hadith says: if we don't marry righteous woman we'll be losers. So, if we chose relations based on family status we are not following the right path and ultimately we'll be losers. Thats what I try to say.

Comment: @TabrezAhmed scholars have mentioned that it's *permissible* to marry for all or any combination of the four. You're saying that it's haram; that is not correct.

Comment: @ashes999, I never mentioned its Haraam. I said it is not right to do so. The hadith too mentions the same. Perhaps my words are a little stern. Would appreciate if you edit the answer reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add to the above very good answer to this question is that any kind of division among Muslim is haram. So dividing yourself among different caste is also Haram.

> As mentioned in Quran, IN Surat Al Anaam. Chapter 6, Verse 159.

إِنَّ الَّذِينَ فَرَّقُوا دِينَهُمْ وَكَانُوا شِيَعًا لَسْتَ مِنْهُمْ فِي شَيْءٍ ۚ إِنَّمَا أَمْرُهُمْ إِلَى اللَّهِ ثُمَّ يُنَبِّئُهُمْ بِمَا كَانُوا يَفْعَلُونَ

Indeed,  those  who  have  divided  their  religion  and  become  sects  -   you,  [O  Muhammad], are  not  [associated]  with  them  in  anything.  Their  affair  is  only  [left]  to Allah ;  then  He will  inform  them  about  what  they  used  to  do.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays no parents are ready to get a groom on seeing the person belief towards Allah.They see only the status it only applicable to this temporary world not to the permanent world (Janna).I would like to tell one thing to all men and women think about ur life in Janna and take decision of your marriages. The wealth that can't be taken towards the permanent world (Janna)

Comment: I suggest you to look here:[How do I write a good answer?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Im from Kerala state Malappuram district in kerala Malappuram district is the district which majority of Muslims are living. In Islam is strictly prohibited cast system but in kerala there is a cast they are known as Barber family. At the time of marriage other family's guys didn't take girl from barber family they don't give girl to barber family if they guy is much qualified and having high profile job. It mostly happening where  majority of muslims are living side while compared with other state.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).