# What if a girl is not happy with her parents' decision for her husband due to caste?

Tags: nikah, practical-islam, sunni, parents, caste

What does Islam say if a girl is not happy with the guy which her family found her, because of [caste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caste) issues?

The guy she likes keeps sending his proposal in the right way through the parents.  And the boy is well established and able to give her the perfect life.  Now what does Islam say about the girl parents' decision?

Can a girl reject her parents opinion, or should she just keep quiet?

If she gets married and can't live happily with the parents selected guy, who is responsible for it?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to learn more about our site and model by taking our 2 min. [tour] and checking our [help]. Here some relevant posts http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12410/my-father-refuses-to-let-me-marry-a-boy-because-of-caste-is-caste-an-importan and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1841/caste-system-or-restriction-for-making-an-alliance

Comment: she can always reject, so can the father (father permission is only required for first marriage). The father can never force her daughter to marry a man...

Answer (score 1):

Forcing your daughter to marry someone against her will is haram (forbidden).

Shaikh Abd al-Aziz ibn Baz, a Saudi Arabian Islamic scholar and a leading proponent of the Salafi form of Islam, and Grand Mufti of Saudi Arabia from 1993 until his death in 1999, said that forcing your daughter to marry someone she doesn't want to marry him is forbidden in Islam and any sexual contact between them will be sin (source: [Ibn Baz fatwa website](https://www.binbaz.org.sa/noor/10848), but it's in Arabic).

So:

1. Can a girl reject her parents opinion, or should she just keep quiet?

   Yes she can reject him and her parents can't force her to.
2. If she gets married and can't live happily with the parents selected guy, who is responsible for it?

   Her parents are the responsible one and they will be judged for that, and her husband too if he knew that she didn't want him as her husband.

Answer (score 1):

She shouldn't keep quiet. If she doesn't like the guy she is getting married to then she shouldn't marry him and the parents have no right to force her to marry him. Allah said in the Quran (what means):

> O ye who believe! Ye are forbidden to inherit women against their will. Nor should ye treat them with harshness, that ye may take away part of the dower [money given by the husband to the wife for the marriage contract] ye have given them, except where they have been guilty of open lewdness; on the contrary live with them on a footing of kindness and equity. If ye take a dislike to them it may be that ye dislike a thing, and God brings about through it a great deal of good.
>
> (Quran, 4:19)